# Encrypting data with a public key in Node.js

Tags: node.js, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I need to encrypt a string using a public key (.pem file), and then sign it using a private key (also a .pem).

I am loading the .pem files fine:

```
publicCert = fs.readFileSync(publicCertFile).toString();
```

But after hours of scouring Google, I can't seem to find a way to encrypt data using the public key. In PHP I simply call openssl_public_encrypt(), but I don't see any corresponding function in Node.js or in any modules.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

A library is not necessary. Enter [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).

Here's a janky little module you could use to encrypt/decrypt strings with RSA keys:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey);
    var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt);
    var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
};

var decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey = function(toDecrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey);
    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toDecrypt, "base64");
    var decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, buffer);
    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
};

module.exports = {
    encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey: encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey,
    decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey: decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey
}
```

I would recommend not using synchronous *fs* methods where possible, and you could use [promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) to make this better, but for simple use cases this is the approach that I have seen work and would take.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can only encrypt small amounts (up to 245 bytes) of data with public key and for larger amounts you should use AES256 with the private key encrypted using a public-private pair. See this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security

Comment: "crypto.publicEncrypt" doesn't work in node.js, same as a lot of functions from 'crypto'

Comment: Amazing :D Just one more thing, the key file should be in .pem format: ```openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -outform pem > id_rsa.pem```

Comment: what if I have the key in a .der file?

Comment: And what if the privateKey is enocder and encrypted using a passphrase? I can't find the right method call of crypto.privateDecrypt()

Comment: @maroodb generate your public and private keys using openssl  keys tool generator ( https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/ ) and run these commands  ( https://rietta.com/blog/2012/01/27/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/ ) to create a pair of public.pem and private.pem files and pass these files to the crypto.privateDecrypt()  function.

Comment: @Prabhat Mishra I am not asking about how to generate keys ;)

Comment: Please any one will help if u want to achieve using crypto. I am able to encrypt using ```crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buffer)``` but for the decrypting the output using ```crypto.publicDecrypt(key, buffer)``` is not working.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar just looking at your code it looks like you could be using the same key for encryption and decryption.  Check that you are encrypting with publicKey and decrypting with privateKey

Comment: Yes @jacobmckay you are right. I am using the same public key

Comment: Your example uses RSA, which [security experts argue against using anymore](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/07/08/fuck-rsa/).

Comment: @maroodb:  You can call `privateDecrypt` like this: `var decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({key: privateKey.toString(), passphrase: 'top secret'}, buffer);`

Answer (score 34):

I tested this in Node.js 10, you can use encrypt/decrypt functions (small changes on [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-a-public-key-in-node-js/31061352#31061352)):

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

function encrypt(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
  const absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey)
  const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, 'utf8')
  const buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt, 'utf8')
  const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer)
  return encrypted.toString('base64')
}

function decrypt(toDecrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey) {
  const absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey)
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, 'utf8')
  const buffer = Buffer.from(toDecrypt, 'base64')
  const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
    {
      key: privateKey.toString(),
      passphrase: '',
    },
    buffer,
  )
  return decrypted.toString('utf8')
}

const enc = encrypt('hello', `public.pem`)
console.log('enc', enc)

const dec = decrypt(enc, `private.pem`)
console.log('dec', dec)
```

---

For the keys you can generate them with

```
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs')
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto')

function generateKeys() {
  const { privateKey, publicKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs1',
      format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs1',
      format: 'pem',
      cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
      passphrase: '',
    },
  })

  writeFileSync('private.pem', privateKey)
  writeFileSync('public.pem', publicKey)
}
```

Comment: It took me days but I finally found an explaination why this would not work in Russian so I thought to add that here http://qaru.site/questions/16043509/nodejs-cryptopublicencrypt-error-error0906d06cpem-routinespemreadbiono-start-line it states publicEncrypt uses openssl and it's RSA only so NO using crypto.createECDH secp384r1 will cause an error of "unhandledRejection Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line" in publicEncrypt any advice how to use higher bit Elliptic Keys? also noted Chrome won't go 512 with EC either. This is as of nodejs 11.6 nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Comment: Also when trying to get something encrypted to the browser from node the keys need to be generated in the browser with the public key being imported in node.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this taught me how to use JSON object to pass "passphrase" to the privateDecrypt function.

Answer (score 8):

The updated public/private decrypt and encryption module is *[URSA](https://github.com/Obvious/ursa)*. The node-rsa module is outdated.

> This Node module provides a fairly complete set of wrappers for the
> RSA public/private key crypto functionality of OpenSSL.

```
npm install ursa
```

Comment: Ursa hasn't been maintained for quite a while. These newer implementations might help: https://github.com/tracker1/cryptico-js and https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa

Answer (score 7):

Use the [node-rsa module](https://github.com/chrisa/node-rsa). Here's a link to the [test.js file that demonstrates usage](https://github.com/chrisa/node-rsa/blob/master/test/test.js).

Comment: Maybe I need to get more familiar with RSA encryption. I read the docs on crypto a dozen times trying to see how to do what I needed, but I didn't find anything. 

You are saying createCipheriv() will do what I need, but I don't even know what "iv" is. I guess it is because it is more abstracted in PHP and other languages. I'll play around with that function and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: After reading more about createCipheriv it looks like it isn't asymmetric encryption (public/private key encryption). I don't think it will fill my needs. Crypto does have the ability to sign an encrypted string with a private key, which makes me wonder why I can't encrypt using a public key. Seems strange, or else I am missing something entirely.

Comment: iv is an initialization vectior. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Comment: I didn't see that you edited your answer. That actually looks like it might do the job! I will test it and see.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: URSA is your best bet. It's really funky that this doesn't come standard with Node.js' *crypto*.

Every other solutions I found either doesn't work in Windows or aren't actually encryption libraries. URSA, [recommended by Louie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-a-public-key-in-node-js/17541703#17541703), looks like the best bet. If you don't care about Windows, you're even more golden.

Note on Ursa: I had to install OpenSSL along with something called "Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables" in order to get the npm install to work. Get that junk here: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

The breakdown:

- Annoying additional manual installation steps for Windows
- https://github.com/Obvious/ursa - probably the best of the lot
- Not compatible with Windows
- https://npmjs.org/package/rsautl - says BADPLATFORM
- https://github.com/katyo/node-rsa - node-waf isn't available on Windows
- https://github.com/paspao/simple_rsa_encrypt - unistd.h isn't on windows
- https://npmjs.org/package/pripub - large amounts of linker errors, also not on GitHub

Not encryption libraries

- https://github.com/substack/secure-peer
- https://github.com/substack/rsa-json - just generates keys, but doesn't use them
- https://github.com/substack/rsa-unpack - just unpacks PEM strings

This is literally all I could find.

Comment: node-rsa do not rely on node-waf anymore. It's browser compatible.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported natively by Node.js version v0.11.13 or below, but it seems that next version of Node.js (a.k.a v0.12) will support this.

Here is the clue: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12/lib/crypto.js#L358

See   `crypto.publicEncrypt` and `crypto.privateDecrypt`

Here is the future documentation for this
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/doc/api/crypto.markdown#cryptopublicencryptpublic_key-buffer

Comment: Time for an update (***without*** "Update:", "Edit:". etc.)?