# RSA Public Key from Java into NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, rsa

I'm having some trouble with using a public key from Java to encrypt within NodeJS.

I've created an RSA key within `keytool` and output the public key as a base64 encoded string.

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
byte[] pubKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
String pubKeyBase64 = encoder.encodeToString(pubKeyBytes);
```

I then took the the base64 encoded public key, wrapped it in `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` and used it to encrypt, then base64 encode a string within node.

```
const encryptedBuffer = crypto.publicEncrypt(encodedPublicKey, buffer);
const encryptedEncodedText = encryptedBuffer.toString("base64");
```

When I try to decrypt the `encryptedEncodedText` (base64 decoding first) within Java, it throws a `BadPadding` exception.  Interestingly, if I export the private key to a PEM, Node can't decrypt with it either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-public-key-in-node-js

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that answer.  I'm not sure what I'm missing from that post.

Comment: Also, if I use an OpenSSL public / private key, the encryption / decryption works fine in node, so I'm doing something wrong, or misunderstanding something from the Java side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and testing, it turned out to be a padding issue.

The public key provided to Node did was not being passed a passphrase, so it defaulted to `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` as per the documentation:

[crypto.publicEncrypt](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer)

When decrypting on the Java side, it is necessary to inform Java of that padding as follows:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
```

This fixed the issue, and allowed messages to be exchanged between Java and NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem. For me, it works fine. I suspect the only problematic step can be when you are creating the PEM file manually. Be sure to:

- If you are copying the key string from any console, remove unwanted characters from the beginning and/or end.
- And a new line character (`\n`) after `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and before `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

like below:

```
var key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCqwEldwNI5s1LkUzwyQZkPQQFpgtj29W7RcHgdwAbUOe31Q8bybAgzg5cUMqdIQlQHq6S5dxsSJBTDCZozSu+pxtKqRLz0JjtCTZD5gS+CJR9DlXH5GgJt+KDiO6olbKiVsP/tsMPgRCFKUMiMKU+dA06dwrUqJlC1k/JzuYVrbwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

var plaintext = "hello world"
var buffer = new Buffer(plaintext, "utf8")
console.log(crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buffer))
```

To avoid all these issues, you can directly generate PEM file from Java using the [bouncycastle library](https://www.txedo.com/blog/java-generate-rsa-keys-write-pem-file/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try!

Comment: So something to note, it encrypts in node just fine, when I try to decrypt what I encrypted in node within the Java code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work as in? seems like encoding related problem.

Comment: When I try to decrypt, it gives me a bad padding exception, it very well could be a encoding problem, I'm not sure.