# Asymmetric Encryption using Nodejs Crypto module

Tags: node.js, cryptojs, encryption-asymmetric

I want to use the crypto module of nodejs10, to make an asymmetric encryption.

I find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-public-key-in-node-js) 
But when I try to run the code below I got this error:

```
return method(toBuf(key), buffer, padding, passphrase);
           ^
Error: error:0608B096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init:operation not supported for this keytype.
```

The code:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
const passphrase = "mySecret"

var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey);
  var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
  var buffer = new Buffer(toEncrypt);
  var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
  return encrypted.toString("base64");
};

var decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey = function(toDecrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey) {
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey);
  var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
  var buffer = new Buffer(toDecrypt, "base64");
  //var decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, buffer);
  const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
    {
      key: privateKey.toString(),
      passphrase: passphrase,
    },
    buffer,
  )
  return decrypted.toString("utf8");
};

const { writeFileSync } = require('fs')
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto')

function generateKeys() {
  const { privateKey, publicKey } = generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
    namedCurve: 'secp256k1',
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem',
      cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
      passphrase: passphrase,
    },
  })

  writeFileSync('private.pem', privateKey)
  writeFileSync('public.pem', publicKey)
}

generateKeys();

let a = encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey("hello", "public.pem")
let b = decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey(a, "private.pem");
console.log(b)
```

I didn't find what is the problem, it seems like the problem with the passphrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating a few parameters on the private key generation will make this work:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
const passphrase = "mySecret"

var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathToPublicKey);
    var publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt);
    var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
};

var decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey = function(toDecrypt, relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey) {
    var absolutePath = path.resolve(relativeOrAbsolutePathtoPrivateKey);
    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    var buffer = Buffer.from(toDecrypt, "base64");
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(
        {
            key: privateKey.toString(),
            passphrase: passphrase,
        },
        buffer,
    )
    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
};

const { writeFileSync } = require('fs')
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto')

function generateKeys() {
    const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', 
    {
            modulusLength: 4096,
            namedCurve: 'secp256k1', 
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem'     
            },     
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',
                cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
                passphrase: passphrase
            } 
    });
    
    writeFileSync('private.pem', privateKey)
    writeFileSync('public.pem', publicKey)
}

generateKeys();

let a = encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey("hello", "public.pem")
let b = decryptStringWithRsaPrivateKey(a, "private.pem");
console.log(b)
```

Comment: What you mean by the default cipher ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you might give it a try, I believe the modulus length was the missing piece of the puzzle!

Comment: The default cipher doesn't mean anything actually! (My mistake, I misread the docs, it would actually leave the key unencrypted). However since I've updated the answer we're now using aes-256-cbc so we are specifying a strong cipher for the key.

Comment: Great, good to hear, I think the issue really was that the error message you were receiving was very confusing!

Comment: Oops, I found that this use rsa encryption :p , I am looking for EC encryption

Comment: Hmmmm.. tricky to find the correct parameters for EC key pair generation..

Comment: You should update "new Buffer(.... )" to "Buffer.from(...)"

Comment: Ah yes indeed,  new Buffer is deprecated. I shall update.  Thank you!

Comment: How do I avoid "/" while encrypting? Update- Got it. I had to encrypt using hex, instead of base64