# How to Encrypt Data in Javascript with RSA public key?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, cryptojs

Server generates RSA public and private keys and store them in the session. Over a server call the client html page recieves the public key. Now I want to encrypt data using it. I have tried using jsencrypt but it doesn't recognize the public key my server generates. Gives false when I call encrypt after setting the public key. I think the key is 2048 bits. Not sure about the encoding though. How to encrypt data using this key? Any help is appreciated.

```
Sample public key generated by server: 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
```

Edit: As suggested by many, I tried using crypto:

```
let crypto;
try {
  crypto = require('crypto');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('crypto support is disabled!');
}
var encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey = function(toEncrypt, publicKey) {
  var buffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt,'utf8');
  var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
  return encrypted.toString("base64");
};
console.log(encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey('MyText','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'));
```

It is throwing the below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
    at push../node_modules/parse-asn1/fixProc.js.module.exports (fixProc.js:19)
    at parseKeys (index.js:27)
    at Object.publicEncrypt (publicEncrypt.js:30)
    at encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey (App.js:20)
    at Module.<anonymous> (App.js:23)
    at Module../src/App.js (App.js:727)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.css?f3f6:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.0 (test.css?2a93:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685645/rsa-encryption-javascript

Comment: I think it's rather a duplicate of [Encrypting data with Public Key in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-public-key-in-node-js)

Comment: tried using crypto js to encrypt and looks like it's failing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

you should add `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

like this

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQE...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
```

Comment: Be careful, after and before the key must be 'enter'. I put it in js with \n