# Javascript encryption and decryption using public and private key

Tags: javascript, encryption, key, client-side

I am not sure if this is even possible, but...
I have a web-based client server application. I would like my client to be able to send encrypted data (like a file) using a public key of sorts to be stored on the server. I would then like a single authorized person to be able to download and decrypt the data/file using his own private key. My thought is that since the encryption and decryption would need to take place client-side I would need to use Javascript. Is there a library that does this, or that I could incorporate to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto is usable?

Comment: Looks like it is already being [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-public-key-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks @ogabekyusupov, but that refers to a built in node module which is not actually client-side. I am aware that there are plenty of server-side solutions. I need something that can be done within the client's web browser. (I don't care if it didn't work in Internet Explorer ;-)